# Shared Catalog / Tagging of pictures

Tags: photos, image-gallery

I'm looking for a solution - preferably web based - to catalog / categorize / tag pictures.
I have 15000 pictures on a NAS, I want users to be able to categorize/tag the photos, to allow searching later on.

Any idea ?

Nota: it should crawl the NAS every day, not go through an "import" process. I don't want duplicate any of the files...

Thanks !

Comment: Well, after all the time spent looking for an existing solution, it seems that we're going to develop our own (in PHP/MySQL/CSS). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use picasa client for my photo album (over 20K pics on my NAS), and it works great.

Though it's tagging info is only available from a single computer.

However, you can [this article](http://www.cloudave.com/876/how-to-guide-picasa-multiple-computers-multiuser-network-nas-shared-2/) to share the info between computers.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Picasa, but it doesn't match the categorizing/tagging needs. I actually want to put each photo in few categories and tag them as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Zoph](http://www.zoph.org/c/) is a multi-user web based photo management system built on PHP and MySQL.  If you haven't already written your own, it might be a place to start.

Wow.. I've just noticed how old the original question is. Oh well, perhaps this will be of help to someone.